# Why does my `for` loop show infinite numbers?

Tags: java, for-loop, infinite-loop

This is my code:

```
package practice;    

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i =+ 2) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `i=+2` does? Did you mean `i+=2`?

Comment: That's a fun mistake. I like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake. You may have wanted to have i increment by 2 each time by writing

```
 i+=2
```

but instead you wrote

```
 i =+2
```

which means that i is always equal to 2. The for loop condition you gave

```
 i < 5
```

means keep looping while i is smaller than 5, and since i is always 2, it will keep looping forever

Comment: Ohhhhhh thats for the clarification. Thanks!

Comment: you are quite welcome, and feel free to accept this as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` sets `i`'s value to `+2` (same as `2`) after each loop because you inverted the `+` and `=` symbols:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i =+ 2)
```

So it does infinite loop because your `for`'s condition `i < 5` is always true, since `i` starts at `0` (`0 < 5` is true) and then, after each loop, `i` is set to `2` (`2 < 5` is also true).

Try this:

```
package practice;    

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i += 2) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }         
    }
}
```